# How to completely remove/disable isotope after animation finishes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-isotope

I'm using isotope js library to give some sorting animation to my div objects. Everything is fine until I preform some other action that I've programmed before that used to work until I applied isotope.js.

The problem is that the container div on which I'm applying isotope is affected by isotope. This affected div prevents me to make some actions that I programmed before.

Briefly, how do I remove the effects of isotope? How do I get rid of it?

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/eugensunic/so1axnup/1/) is my fiddle, after the event occurs I would like the disable action to happen:

Code:

```
 var $container = $('#container').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.item',
    isResizeBound: false,
    getSortData: {
        weight: function (itemElem) {
            var weight = $(itemElem).find('.weight').text();
            return parseFloat(weight.replace(/[\(\)]/g, ''));
        }
    }
});
// bind sort button click
$('.button').click(function () {
    var sortByValue = $(this).attr('data-sort-by');
    $container.isotope({
        sortBy: sortByValue
    });
});
$container.isotope('on', 'arrangeComplete', function () {
    alert('arrange is complete'); 
    //remove isotope effects completly, disable it somehow,
});
```

Comment: What are "some actions"?  It seems finding out why your other code conflicts with isotope is a better option that disabling isotope. Why use isotope if you are just going to disable it?

Comment: sorry for the late response, I updated my fiddle and tried to demonstrate the problem. If you click on add icon button, it prepends to the div container  but does NOT push the content to the right side. Try to press weight and you will see the prepended  divs but somehow they are not pushing the others div: http://jsfiddle.net/eugensunic/so1axnup/2/

Comment: I've made numerous scripts to handle this, but am still having huge problems... is there something which would cut my work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of removing isotope, try this, [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/macsupport/uq3vp9rj/):

```
 $(".buttonz").click(function () {
 var $newItems = $('<div class="item"><p class="weight">7</p></div>');
 $('#container').prepend( $newItems).isotope( 'reloadItems' ).isotope({ sortBy: 'original-order' });

 });
```

Comment: you gotta be kidding me right, you saved my life temporarily xd, I don't know how on earth I missed that in the documentation

Comment: Happy to save a life! At some point you ought to update isotope to v2. Some things ahve changed but better performance.